# How to auto increment a value in one table when inserted a row in another table

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers, auto-increment, sql-view

I currently have two tables:

`Table 1` has a unique ID and a count.

`Table 2` has some data columns and one column where the value of the unique ID of `Table 1` is inside.

When I insert a row of data in `Table 2`, the the count for the row with the referenced unique id in `Table 1` should be incremented.
Hope I made myself clear. I am very new to PostgreSQL and SQL in general, so I would appreciate any help how to do that. =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could achieve that with [triggers](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/triggers.html).
Be sure to cover all kinds of write access appropriately if you do. `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`.
Also be aware that `TRUNCATE` on `Table 2` or manual edits in `Table 1` could break data integrity.

I suggest you consider a [**`VIEW`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createview.html) instead to return aggregated results that are automatically up to date. Like:

```
CREATE VIEW tbl1_plus_ct AS
SELECT t1.*, t2.ct
FROM   tbl1 t1
LEFT JOIN  (
   SELECT tbl1_id, count(*) AS ct
   FROM   tbl2
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) t2 USING (tbl1_id)
```

If you use a `LEFT JOIN`, all rows of `tbl1` are included, even if there is no reference in `tbl2`. With a regular `JOIN`, those rows would be omitted from the `VIEW`.

For all or much of the table, it is fastest to aggregate `tbl2` first in a subquery, *then* join to `tbl1` - like demonstrated above.

Instead of creating a view, you could also just use the query directly, and if you only fetch a single row, or only few, this alternative form would perform better:

```
SELECT t1.*, count(t2.tbl1_id) AS ct
FROM   tbl1 t1
LEFT   JOIN  tbl2 t2 USING (tbl1_id)
WHERE  t1.tbl1_id = 123  -- for example
GROUP  BY t1.tbl1_id     -- being the primary key of tbl1!
```